# Facebook, Pidgin, and 2-factor authentication

Tags: facebook-messenger

I've been using FB's App Passwords feature for years now to use Pidgin while I have 2-fac enabled.  However, about a week ago my password broke, so I went to FB to enable a new one. And it looks like the feature has been completely removed.  None of the guides I can find online are helpful (all of them tell me to go to a link that doesn't exist) and the FB official help page no longer exists either.

Is there an alternate way to use 2-fac and app passwords? Or is Facebook that insistent that you never go outside its ecosystem that it prefers that people get hacked without 2-fac?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same happenned to me a while ago. They activated the two-factor authentication without prompting me. The "app passwords" appears to have been discontinued. Because it's enabled the "Facebook Protect" feature, the 2FA feature is required and it seems there is no way to disable the "Facebook Protect".
More information here: [Liburple issues page on Github](https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/issues/526)